# Permission Set Group Recalculation Failed 2000+ Fields

Tags: governorlimits, permission-sets, limits, permission-set-groups

We are encountering Permission Set Groups that are stuck in the `Failed` state, I was able to find: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003eq1QAA, and after removing all of the Permission Sets added to a group, it succeeded in recalculating (Failed -> Updating -> Updated, state).

I can't find [any mention](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups.htm&type=5) of this 2000 Fields limit. Is it an undocumented limit?

- If so does anyone advice on how to calculate the total number of fields in a Permission Set Group (?)
- Do PSGs that have multiple PSs that grant access to the *same* field count toward this total?

Comment: The fix of that KI was to not run into an issue with 2000 or more fields. I'd put in a support case if you haven't already to confirm why this is occurring then.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only documentation I find from Salesforce related to the 2,000 field limitation for Permission Set Groups: [https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAyIuAAK/permission-set-group-remains-in-a-failed-status#:~:text=A%20permission%20set%20group%20will,more%20than%202000%20field%20permission.&text=Update%20the%20permission%20set%20group,more%20than%202000%20field%20permissions](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAyIuAAK/permission-set-group-remains-in-a-failed-status#:%7E:text=A%20permission%20set%20group%20will,more%20than%202000%20field%20permission.&text=Update%20the%20permission%20set%20group,more%20than%202000%20field%20permissions).

There are tools to pull the number of fields in a permission set into a CSV like SecurityZen. That would likely be the best way to calculate total number of fields in the permission sets that make up the PSG.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.